# CSP block and report only headers

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

Say I have a chrome extension which is adding headers to block and report cross site scripting. When I try to have two Content Security Policy headers, one being report only, both don't seem to work. Only one or the other. Is this a bug in chromium? The spec is clear that they should not interfere with one another.

I hypothesize there may be a special case for the `sandbox` directive, that if I break it out to its constituents it may work. Another possible solution could be switching the order, but still, only one works in that case. Otherwise, worst case there is a bug in chromium preventing both Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only and Content-Security-Policy from operating normally.

Here are the headers I'm adding:

```
var csp1 = {
    'name': 'Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only',
    'value': "sandbox; report-uri http://localhost/csp"
}
headers.push(csp1);

var csp2 = {
    'name': 'Content-Security-Policy',
    'value': "default-src 'none'; report-uri http://localhost/csp"
}
headers.push(csp2);
```

I tried searching the chromium codebase with no obvious solution and I'm hoping this is something somebody has run into before and can help me out.

Any chrome devs out there who can answer this question?

EDIT: I just found this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=503730

It says there was indeed a bug on chromium preventing both CSP and CSPRO from working together, and that it was fixed. Yet it still does not work for me.

Comment: No errors in the background console? Try [logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) or chrome://tracing. Also, maybe it works only when https report URL is used.

Comment: The problem is with the `sandbox` directive. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=594645

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This directive is not supported in the  element or by the
>   Content-Security-policy-Report-Only header field.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox